# Wordpress links in menu change destination urls to "#"

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hyperlink, hashtag

I'm working on this website:

http://www.aiteq.it

and as you should see too, the links in the left-side menu all point to "#" 
(which obviously makes them useless)

I wasn't the first one to work on this site so I don't know much about what was done with it, and I don't know much about Wordpress, but the menu in the Wordpress panel seems ok, all the link point directly to pages.

Two wierd thing:

1: if you view the source code in a browser, the < a > tags will display the correct href parameter (the right url)

2: ...they seem to work on tablet browsers, although they don't in all of the browsers I tried on my laptop

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance to anyone who spends time to answer

edit: the links do sometimes work (very rarely) when loading the page, but go baco to "#" as soon as it is reloaded

update: looks like it works for some people, if the navigation menu has been opened after letting the page completely load. It only does so on Internet Explorer for me, chrome and firefox still see only "#" links even minutes after the page is done loading.

Well this seems like an issue that will stay unsolved..

Comment: All of the links are fine...You're possibly experiencing a chaching issue on your laptop.

Comment: @rnevius Here they only link to hashtags too

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I already deleted my chrome cache several times, did you try reloading the page and they still work?

Comment: Yeah...Chrome, Firefox, IE...all work fine. Multiple refreshes.

Comment: that's even weirder, Daan seems to have the same problem as me. Also, it did work on a tablet I'm testing

Comment: Yeah...curious for other people to chime in.

Comment: @mevius thanks for taking the time to test it. ...I just hope this wasn't the last view on this question, things seem to die if they stay unsolved for the first 10 minutes, on this kind of websites :P

Comment: Load page and click left navigation bar before the page is done rendering completely causes the links to only have a `#`.  If you wait for the page to completely load before opening the navigation menu it works fine.

Comment: So maybe you have some javascript selector that looks for the closed navigation menu and only updates the urls in that scenario.

Comment: @Overachiever I have confirmed that to be the issue. Weird bug. I'm now seeing it.

Comment: So that works for you? I still get "#" even after waiting minutes after the page is done loading...

Comment: ..it only seems to work on Internet Explorer, for me